# How to say "all in all"

Tags: word-choice, translation, idioms

I have been many times blocked in a conversation because I have no way to translate "all in all" in those general contexts:

- All in all it takes 15 minutes to get there
- All in all this movie was quite fun

How to translate this while staying natural and perhaps by using different idioms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All in all it takes 15 minutes to get there
**全部で**15分かかる。
([more examples of this structure](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%E2%80%9D%E5%85%A8%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A7%2a%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E2%80%9D&safe=off&start=90))

All in all this movie was quite fun
この映画は**全体的に**おもしろかった。
([more examples](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%E2%80%9D%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB%E3%81%AF%E5%85%A8%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E2%80%9D&safe=off), [more examples](https://www.google.co.jp/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%E2%80%9D%E5%85%A8%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E9%9D%A2%E7%99%BD%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E2%80%9D&safe=off), [more](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%85%A8%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB))

[This dictionary](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=all%20in%20all) might help as well. It includes some useful phrases like 全体として見れば.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's using all-in-all in two different senses. The first example is in the sense of "in total" whereas the second case is in the sense of "in a word". For the latter, I'd suggest you can use something like `[概]{がい}して` or `一言で`, e.g.: `概して言えば面白い映画だった。`

Answer (score 2):

Another option I haven't seen yet is つまり, which is to the effect of "In short...", and is used as a lead-in for a brief summary.

Here are some examples taken from the Tanaka Corpus:

> 祖母【そぼ】は耳【みみ】が遠【とお】い、つまり、耳【みみ】が少【すこ】し不自由【ふじゆう】なのだ。
> My grandmother is hard of hearing. In other words she is slightly deaf.
>
> 彼【かれ】はとても太【ふと】っている、つまり、３００ポンドも体重【たいじゅう】があるのだ。
> He is very fat, that is, he weighs 300 pounds.
>
> つまり、英語【えいご】はもはや、イギリスの人々【ひとびと】だけの言語【げんご】ではないということです。
> It shows that English is no longer the language only of the people of England.

The last example, in particular, I think captures that nuance that you're looking for.